# midasr package - Differences between forecast() and select_and_forecast()?

Tags: forecasting

I'm doing midas forecasting with the midasr package. Until now I've been using midasr's forecast(), but I just stumbled upon the select_and_forecast() function.

I'm trying to gain a sense towards which of these is the "bread and butter", "go to", base forecast function that all the cool kids straightaway go to.

The example in the help section of select_and_forecast() is really confusing me when it comments out half the example with a preceding #Do not run. Does this mean the function is broken and under development?

Comment: As far as I know, the "do not run" code is automatically generated when building R package documentation. Sometimes, for whatever reason, a package author may not want example code to run when checking or building a package, so the code can be left like that. In other words, the commented out code may not have been put there with any intention. As for the functions, [@mpiktas](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/2116/mpiktas) may be generous to share an answer for you.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the insight regarding the "do not run" code. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find further details regarding their usage from the following paper

Ghysels, E., Kvedaras, V., & Zemlys, V. (2013). Mixed frequency data sampling regression models: the R Package midasr. *Journal of Statistical Software*. *20*(2)